# ESP32-S2-MINI-1 Access Point gives the same address to different clients

Tags: esp32

I've ESP32-S2-MINI-1 configured as access point and 5 IPcameras connected to this access point,
my problem is that more ipcameras received the same IP from ESP32-S2-MINI-1, for example this is the answer to a broadcast request, each ipcameras responds two times and for example ipcamera ACTO018066 and ipcamera ACTO017101 have the same ipaddress 192.168.43.3 .

1. Is this a bug of ESP32-S2-MINI-1 ?
2. How I can solve this problem?
3. The firmware for ESP32-S2-MINI-1 is version:2.1.0.0(0b76313 - ESP32S2 - Aug 20 2020 05:57:43)
   SDK version:v4.2-dev-2044-gdd3c032
   compile time(b5e1674):Aug 21 2020 05:00:52
   Bin version:2.1.0(MINI)
   is it available a newer release?

Thanks, Antonio

```
    +IPD,0,524:DH192.168.43.3 255.255.255.0192.168.43.1192.168.43.1ðÈÄÙ~':ACTO018066 ...

    +IPD,0,524:DH192.168.43.3 255.255.255.0192.168.43.1192.168.43.1ðÈÄÙ~':ACTO018066 ...

    +IPD,0,524:DH192.168.43.2 255.255.255.0192.168.43.1192.168.43.1ðÈÄÎœm3ACTO011614 ...

    +IPD,0,524:DH192.168.43.2 255.255.255.0192.168.43.1192.168.43.1ðÈÄÎœm3ACTO011614 ...

    +IPD,0,524:DH192.168.43.3 255.255.255.0192.168.43.1192.168.43.1ðÈÄ²¤†ñACTO017101 ...

    +IPD,0,524:DH192.168.43.3 255.255.255.0192.168.43.1192.168.43.1ðÈÄ²¤†ñACTO017101HBJJR ...

    +IPD,0,524:DH192.168.43.2 255.255.255.0192.168.43.18.8.8.8192.168.43.1»&P)EnACTO005825 ...

    +IPD,0,524:DH192.168.43.2 255.255.255.0192.168.43.18.8.8.8192.168.43.1»&P)EnACTO005825 ...

    +IPD,0,524:DH192.168.43.4 255.255.255.0192.168.43.18.8.8.8192.168.43.1»&á2Æ ACTO005665 ...

    +IPD,0,524:DH192.168.43.4 255.255.255.0192.168.43.18.8.8.8192.168.43.1»&á2Æ ACTO005665 ...
0,CLOSED

OK
```

Comment: update the AT firmware to 2.4.1. many bugs were fixed

Comment: 2.4.1 seems not available for esp32-s2 mini 1

Comment: then use 2.4.0.

Comment: Only version available for esp32-s2 mini 1 is 2.1.0.0

Comment: so I don't know. there is a MINI 1 AT fw without specifying S2 or C3